# Label size in sankey plots (riverplot package)

Tags: r, visualization, sankey-diagram, riverplot

**Use case:**
I am using the [riverplot package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/riverplot/riverplot.pdf) to plot sankey charts. I need to adjust the text size of the nodes labels in the plot. The default size is too big in my case.

**Problem, what I tried already:**
Unfortunately the package does not work with a `cex` argument. The developer of the package did not provide guidance to me.
r
**Reproduceable example:**

```
library(riverplot)

plot(riverplot.example())
```

Generates:

[image]

**Question:**

How can I adjust the nodes labels (A, B, ...) to a smaller or larger size than default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package itself doesn't provide any means of setting the text size. (You can see that, if you care, by drilling down through `riverplot:::plot.riverplot()` to `riverplot()` to `riverplot:::draw.nodes()`; the labels are drawn by the last couple of lines of that final function, which just (implicitly) uses the global value of `cex` et al.)

If you're just wanting to uniformly magnify or reduce the size of node labels, though, there is a relatively easy fix. You can just temporarily reset the global value of `cex`, construct the plot, and then reset `cex` to its original value:

```
library(riverplot)

op <- par(cex=0.8)
plot(riverplot.example())
par(op)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a custom style to a river plot by building on the base default style and avoiding temporarily changing environment settings as in the accepted answer (which is a few years old, so things may have changed with riverplot since then).

To create a custom style with a custom font size:

```
# create a custom style by first copying from the default style
custom.style <- riverplot::default.style()

# change the font size
custom.style$textcex <- 0.8
```

Now just apply your custom style when rendering your plot:

```
plot(my.river.plot, default_style=custom.style)
```